# jQuery Datatable not working when trying to popilate table from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm am trying to populate a table from JavaScript. My problem is that the table is being populated but "No data available in table" is shown, and when I try to search or do something with the data; the data disappears.

I am using this code. First I have the html table

```
<table id="addressTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Locality</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The javascript code appending the table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {               
            $("#addressTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td></tr>");
        }
```

Any ideas how I could solve this problem please? Thanks

Comment: Its an array from which I'm getting the data to populate the table

Comment: can we have your features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the datatable after updation,

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    $("#addressTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td><td>" + features[i].attributes["data"] + "</td></tr>");
}
var oTable = $("#addressTable").dataTable();


oTable.fnDestroy();
$("#addressTable").dataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop Joshi, thats all what I needed!